# Facing error while returning dialogue box in QT :

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to return pointer of QMessageBox from one function to another, but i;m facing the below error :

> error: 'QMessageBox::QMessageBox(const QMessageBox&)' is private
>        Q_DISABLE_COPY(QMessageBox)

code:

```
QMessageBox BoxDraw()
{
QMessageBox *msgBox;
bool retValue=false;
msgBox->setWindowTitle("");
QString qstr = QString::fromStdString(MY_String);
QString qyes = QString::fromStdString(MY_String_YES);
QString qno = QString::fromStdString(MY_String_NO);
msgBox->setText(qstr);
msgBox->setParent(0);
msgBox->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
msgBox->setWindowFlags(Qt::BypassWindowManagerHint);
return *msgBox;
}
```

Calling it from another function like :

```
*global variable* 
QMessageBox *diagBox = NULL;

func A()
{
diagBox = BoxDraw();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy a QMessageBox. Return a pointer

```
QMessageBox* BoxDraw()
{
   QMessageBox *msgBox;
   ...    
   return msgBox;
}
```

BTW: you are missing a `new QMessageBox`.

Comment: Thanks Manni, it was very helpful.
One more doubt :
i have actually implemented GTK dialogue box as shown below :

    GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new (GTK_WINDOW(webkitBrowserWindow),
                                                 flags,
                                                 GTK_MESSAGE_INFO,
                                                 GTK_BUTTONS_OK,
                                                 "%s",message_data->str.str );
Now i want "GTK_BUTTONS_OK" to be replaced with str variable which stores "ok", so that i can change the language.
plz suggest.